# ostream operator overloading << is not defined for a const char[]?

Tags: c++, printing, operator-overloading, ostream

i'm trying to make a Movie class in my C++ project printable , in order to accept following syntax :-

```
Movie movie;
cout << movie;
```

for some reason while implementing the << operator overloading for ostream and Movie, an error occurs .

My code:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Movie& movie){
    os << movie.getName() << "\n" << movie.getRating();
    return os;
}
```

Error:

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const char [2]’)
```

methods getName() and getRating() return string and int, and when using them alone without "\n" it works fine. Problem occurs when trying to use any kind of string that has a constant size.

what is going wrong ?

Comment: Did you `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: omg i can't believe it was that simple. thanks!

Comment: seriously! @Ryan u missed `iostream` -_-